# ORMLite RunTimeException - how pass Object type from previous Activity

Tags: android, ormlite

I have several class for several tables. Each class has the same fields. Int the first activity I choose which table I want to use, then go to another activity. I create there  `RuntimeExceptionDao<Biceps, String> bicepsDao = dao.getBicepsRunTimeDao();` Biceps is name for one table. And I create this dao for each part of the human body, and then I execute the same process, depending the table, it looks like this

```
switch (partia) {
            case "biceps": {

                RuntimeExceptionDao<Biceps, String> bicepsDao = dao.getBicepsRunTimeDao();

                List<Biceps> list = bicepsDao.queryForAll();

                final ArrayAdapter<Biceps> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Biceps>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        Biceps item = arrayAdapter.getItem(position);
                        String idCwiczenia = item.getId();

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Cwiczenia.this, DodajSerie.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("id", idCwiczenia);
                        Cwiczenia.this.startActivity(myIntent);

                    }
                });
            }
            break;
            case "triceps": {

                RuntimeExceptionDao<Triceps, String> tricepsDao = dao.getTricepsRunTimeDao();

                List<Triceps> list = tricepsDao.queryForAll();

                final ArrayAdapter<Triceps> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Triceps>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        Triceps item = arrayAdapter.getItem(position);
                        String idCwiczenia = item.getId();

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Cwiczenia.this, DodajSerie.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("id", idCwiczenia);
                        Cwiczenia.this.startActivity(myIntent);

                    }
                });
            }
            break;
```

So, the code looks pretty the same, and I think it's against "Don't repeat yourself".

My question: Is there a possiblity to create RuntimeExceptionDao and pass object type from previous Activity? It also should be proper to create one List, and one ArrayList, as well

Comment: You should read up on [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html), they will allow you to write the same code once for many different types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create interface `Exercises` with `String getId()` function and implement it in all yours exercise classes (`Biceps`, `Triceps` etc).

Then replace `dao.getBicepsRunTimeDao()` and `dao.getTricepsRunTimeDao()` to some more generic function:

```
public <T extends Exercises> RuntimeExceptionDao<T, String> getDao(Class<T> classt) {
    return RuntimeExceptionDao.createDao(connectionSource, classt);
}
```

Then you can create

```
private <T extends Exercises> void initializeList(Class<T> classt) {
    RuntimeExceptionDao<T, String> dao = dao.getDao(classt);
    List<T> list = dao.queryForAll();

    final ArrayAdapter<T> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<T>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            T item = arrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            String idCwiczenia = item.getId();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Cwiczenia.this, DodajSerie.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("id", idCwiczenia);
            Cwiczenia.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
     });
}
```

You can use this function like that:

```
switch (partia) {
    case "biceps":
        initializeList(Biceps.class);
    break;
    case "triceps":
        initializeList(Triceps.class);
    break;
}
```

You can also pass from first activity `Class<T>` object (its serializable so you can put it in `Bundle`) to avoid using switch-case.

Comment: It works like a charm! But I've created
public <T extends Exercises> RuntimeExceptionDao<T, String> getDao(Class<T> classt) in DatabaseHandler and I was ask to try-catch it, or throw exception. Is it really needed, or I just missed something?

Comment: `RuntimeExceptionDao.createDao()` throws `SQLException` so you need to do something witch that (e.g. show error).